# Laplace distribution from uniform distrubtion

Tags: probability-distributions

Since I'm interested in the simulation of probability distributions on the computer. I want to simulate the Laplace distribution. When I was looking on the laplace distribution wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Related_distributions) my I fell on $log(\frac{X}{Y}) \sim Laplace(0,1)$ for Uniformly distributed X and Y.

Before Using this I wanna ofcourse prove it. So I started writing $P(log(\frac{X}{Y}) \leq x)$, I divided in the cases x<0, x=0 and x>0. But i didn't get any further. Help would be appreciated.

Oh and I ofcourse googled this result, but I only found pages mentioning this, not proving it.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in \mathbb R$, we have
\begin{align*}
  P\left(\log\frac XY \le x\right) &= P\left(\frac XY \le \exp x\right)\\
      &= \int_0^1 P\left(\frac Xy \le \exp x\right)\; dy\\
      &= \int_0^1 P\left(X \le y\exp x\right)\;dy\\
      &= \int_0^1 \min\{y\exp x, 1\}\, dy\\
\end{align*}
For $x \le 0$, $y\exp x \le 1$ for all $y \in [0,1]$, hence
$$ P\left(\log \frac XY\le x\right) = \int_0^1 y\exp x\, dy = \frac 12 \exp x $$
for $x \ge 0$:
\begin{align*}
 P \left(\log \frac XY \le x \right)&= \int_0^{\exp (-x)} y\exp x\,dy +\bigl (1 - \exp(-x)\bigr)\\
  &= \exp x \cdot \frac 12 \exp(-2x) + 1 -\exp(-x)\\
  &= 1 - \frac 12 \exp(-x)
\end{align*}
Hence 
$$ P\left( \log\frac XY \le x\right) = \begin{cases} \frac 12 \exp x & x \le 0 \\ 1 - \frac 12 \exp(-x) & x \ge 0\end{cases} $$
So $\log\frac XY \sim \text{Laplace}(0,1)$.